# Python inheritance --Frames

Tags: wxpython

Can someone explain the below code. As per my reading, Myframe inherits wx.frame but what I don't understand is the below lines thats given in the init method,

```
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title,
                                      pos, size, style, name)
```

Code

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", 
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                 name="MyFrame"):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title,
                                      pos, size, style, name)
        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel,
                                label="Push Me",
                                pos=(50, 50))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bit of code simply allows you to use the parent class's `__init__()` method.
So the attribute-assignment code does not have to be repeated in the child class for those particular attributes.

You could have also done this:

```
        wx.Frame.__init__() # just an example, args omitted
```

But then you are hard-coding the parent class name, and your code becomes less flexible.

---

Aside:
In Python 3 the call to `super()` is simplified to:

```
        super().__init__() # just an example, args omitted
```